# Update both UILabel frame and text simultaneously in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm trying to make an UILabel follow my finger movement (x-axis only) on the screen. I would like to update the UILabel text to the label's current position simultaneously.

However, this causes the label's position to stutter in iOS8. In iOS7 there is no visible stutter. Most of the times the label doesn't even move on iOS8.

Curiously, when I either update the position or the label text individually it works fine and there's no stutter.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

My code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *movableLbl;

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    point.y = self.movableLbl.center.y;

    // Update label position
    self.movableLbl.center = point;

    float totalViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    float percentage = (point.x / totalViewWidth) * 100;

    // Update label text
    [self.movableLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f%%", percentage]];
}
```

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: I tried with and without auto-layout but the result is the same.

Comment: What I meant is - if you're using auto-layout you can't change frames of views like this. You need to change constraints.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I removed all constraints in the view but the problem still exists.

Comment: HI, have you got answer for this?